# MATLAB code to evaluate audio loundness over time

Tags: matlab, audio

can anyone tell me how to evaluate the loudness/intensity over time using MATLAB? By **loudness/intensity over time** I mean this:[image]

In the images above, the "black" one on the top is a sound's **amplitude over time**, and the green line is the corresponding **loudness/intensity over time**. The green line underneath, which is what I want, is generated using [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/).

Can any one tell me, that given a sound input, how can I generate the corresponding **loudness/intensity over time** using MATLAB?

For example, given a input, I can generate the upper one using this MATLAB script:

```
[x,fs] = audioread('soundfile.wav');
t = (0:length(x)-1)/fs;
subplot(211);
plot(t,x);
```

How can I generate the green line then? Thanks.

(ps. Any other programming languages other than MATLAB is welcome as well)

Comment: Do you know the formula of Intensity? Implement it!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Frankly I quite confused with the definition of intensity. In the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity, it's defined as "the sound power per unit area", whose unit is "watt per square meter (W/m2)". But what I want is the one with unit of "dB".

Comment: Then do the conversion!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama can you explain the conversion procedure in a formal answer? Thanks

Comment: The wikipedia link that you mentioned explains the  conversion procedure under the heading "Sound intensity level"

Comment: Do you want me to rewrite it? `Lₗ =10 log₁₀(I/Iₒ) dB`
where `I=Intensity in W/m²` and `Iₒ = 10⁻¹² W/m²`

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Thanks. One more question: In the formula `I = p  v` ,  `v` the velocity can be messured approximately as 340m/s. But how can we messure the `p`? In the image above, the amplitude have both positive and negative values, whereas `p` the pressure can only have positive value. How to do this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

Any audio recording is generally assumed to have units that are proportional to Pascals (Pa).  This is the instantaneous pressure of the sound wave above (positive) or below (negative) the ambient pressure.

(To actually get Pascals from the WAV file, you need to know the calibration factor for your recording system.)

Loudness of sound (in air) is generally reported as Sound Pressure Level (SPL) in decibels. SPL (in dB) and pascals are related as

`Pa_ref = 20e-6;  %reference pressure for SPL
SPL_dB = 10*log10( (Pa / Pa_ref).^2 );`

If you use the instantaneous pressure values (ie, the values straight from the WAV file), this equation will give you the instantaneous SPL.  Based on the graph that you showed, you don't want the instantaneous SPL.  You want a time-smoothed SPL.

To get a time-smoothed SPL, the standard approach is to extract the envelope of the pressure signal.  There are lots of ways of doing this.  One way is to rectify and low-pass filter the signal.  In this case, your processing might look like this:

`%load and calibrate the data
[wav,fs_Hz]=audioread(myfilename);  %load the WAV file
my_cal_factor = 1.0;  %the value for your system to convert the WAV into Pascals
wav_Pa = wav * my_cal_factor;`


`%extract the envelope
smooth_sec = 0.125;  %"FAST" SPL is 1/8th of second.  "SLOW" is 1 second;
smooth_Hz = 1/smooth_sec;
[b,a]=butter(1,smooth_Hz/(fs_Hz/2),'low');  %design a Low-pass filter
wav_env_Pa = sqrt(filter(b,a,wav_Pa.^2));  %rectify, by squaring, and low-pass filter`


`%compute SPL
Pa_ref = 20e-6;  %reference pressure for SPL in Air
SPL_dB = 10.0*log10( (wav_env_Pa ./ Pa_ref).^2 ); % 10*log10 because signal is squared`


`%plot results
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
t_sec = ([1:size(wav_Pa)]-1)/fs_Hz;
plot(t_sec,wav_Pa);
xlabel('Time (sec)');
ylabel('Pressure (Pa)');`


`subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t_sec,SPL_dB);
xlabel('Time (sec)');
ylabel('SPL (dB)');
yl=ylim;ylim(yl(2)+[-80 0]);`

Comment: the code is fine, but i might suggest filtering with some weighting-filter (like [A-weighting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/examples/audio-weighting-filters.html)) if **perceived** loudness, not just SPL is what is desired. [coefficients for two cascaded biquads might be found here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/weightingfilter-class.html).

Comment: I totally agree with filtering to A-weight the results.  My answer was already getting pretty long, so I left it out.  I totally agree, though.

Comment: note also that you are square rooting wave_env_Pa and squaring it right away.

Comment: I did that for clarity...especially when comparing against my initial definition of SPL_dB, which has Pascals be squared.  On a PC (Matlab was the requested format), the wasted cycles of sqrt followed by square are probably inconsequential.  On an embedded platform, it would indeed be stupid to do the operation as I've shown it.  That's a good observation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I ask one more: What is the reason of squaring the `wav_Pa`? If `wav_pa1 = 10 Pa` and `wav_pa2 = -10 Pa`, then squaring both would give you `100` and `100`, which are the same, but initially they have a distance of 20. After squaring them, they are now the same, but initially they are different. What is the reason of ignoring this different ? Thanks.

Comment: You square the Pascals because we are, in effect, computing the RMS value of the sound pressure, just like you'd compute the RMS of a voltage signal.  You take the squareRoot of the Mean of the Square (RMS).  That's the most common way of summarizing the average intensity of alternating signals like electricity and sound.